# Can't configure openconnect with stoken support

Tags: static-libraries, configure

I have installed stoken and works fine. Also I want to using stoken with OpenConnect. When I 'configure/make/make install' openconnect then is compiled without stoken support. I checked 'configure' output and there is line about no-checking libstoken. I tried add path to libs to /etc/ld.so.conf, exported LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_RUN_PATH and nothing work. I have not an idea how to solve it.

```
ldconfig -p | grep stoken
            libstoken.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libstoken.so.1
            libstoken.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libstoken.so

[user@laptop openconnect-7.06]$ ./configure | grep -i stoken
checking for LIBSTOKEN... no

[user@laptop openconnect-7.06]$ ./configure --with-stoken | grep -i stoken
checking for LIBSTOKEN... no
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}"
```